# Problem when deploying smart contract

Tags: smartpy, reveal

I've been trying to create a smart contract on the Tezos blockchain for several times.
I was never able to create a smart contract on this blockchain because of this error.
I use the code that is in this tutorial: https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/using-the-smartpy-ide-to-deploy-tezos-smart-contracts

Each time, I have an error, when I deploy and accept the pre-signature, I receive this error message from the online IDE:
(branch: proto.016-PtMumbai.contract.unrevealed_key)
[image: Erreur]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can use any wallet, you must reveal it. Thats why you are getting an "unrevealed" error. The tool you are using should be checking that for you, and doing it as part of the operation to inject the contract, but its not for some reason

To fix it, open your wallet in a wallet app (e.g. kukai) and perform any operation that triggers a transaction fee. Like delegate to a baker, send XTZ to another account etc. The wallet app will perform a reveal for you when you do this

Comment: Indeed the manager deploying a contract must be revealed, but most CLI applications usually add the revelation to the operation batch if it is not the case. I'm surprised that the  SmartPy IDE doesn't handle this... And maybe it is worth opening an issue there

Comment: There is a "reveal account" button after choosing a wallet if it's unrevealed. Be sure to fund your wallet on the proper network before revealing, here are the faucets: https://teztnets.xyz/